# customizing jquery datepicker=asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

Thanks for forum member I was shown this:
[enter link description here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/default.html)

looked at the source code but could not find where they customize the code to show the nie widget. On my machine if i impleent the dateicker within a gridview, i get plane old datepicker with next and pre text as href rather then the what the widget shows.

how do i customize my .net app to show widget like the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The styling is via CSS files that you can customize and download with jQuery UI.  [Here's a link to ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) which allows you to customize and then download whatever theme you like.  And [here's a link](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Getting_Started) that can help you understand how to work with jQuery UI and the files that are included with it.